# Updating models in a Doctrine Migration

Tags: migration, doctrine

I'm trying to update a model in the context of a Doctrine_Migration. Calling save() on the object doesn't seem to update the database. I also tried calling execute() a Doctrine_Query in the context of a Doctrine_Migration. I tried running getSqlQuery() on the query object and I get a valid query that works if executed in a mysql console, however if I just run the migration normally I get no errors and the execute() doesn't seem to do anything.

How can successfully execute() a query in the context of a migration?

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = Doctrine_Query::create()->update('FooBar')->set('colFoo', '?', 'valBar')->execute();
```

This should do the trick